# GWT time/string formatting

Tags: java, gwt, time, formatting

How can I easily do the following in GWT? (The code below is illegal since `String.format` is not emulated.)

```
long lTime = System.currentTimeMillis() % (24*60*60*1000);
long lHour = lTime/(60*60*1000);
long lMin = lTime/(60*1000)%60;
long lSec = lTime/1000%60;
long lMilli = lTime%1000;
return String.format("%d.%.2d:%.2d.%.4d", lHour, lMin, lSec, lMilli);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) (yes, most of its methods are deprecated, but that's what the GWT team chose) and [`DateTimeFormat`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)